# Login failed for user domain\MachineName$ error in Session Task

Tags: sql-server, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have Informatica PowerCenter installed on my local machine and am able to successfully connect to the local SQL Server Database instance. However when I try to connect to a remote server I am getting 'Login failed for user domain\MachineName$'.

Here is the full Error -

Error connecting to database [
Windows authentication is used to access the Microsoft SQL Server database

Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0:    Login failed for user '<>\<>$'.
SQL State: 28000    Native Error: 18456
State: 1    Severity: 14
SQL Server Message: Login failed for user '<>\<>$'.

Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [] and connection string [<>].].

Can someone throw light on how to get over this?

Comment: Did you provide `sysadmin` rights to your user on sql-server -> server roles ?

Comment: The user only has public role and as far as database roles are concerned it has db_datareader and db_datawriter permissions. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: It can be one of the probable cause according to this : http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/ You may try it.

Comment: @PrabhatG - I am completely aware of how to add users as Administrator. The issue here is on that server I can't be administrator and only have read/write access to the particular database. With such setup I am not sure why my logon is failing.

Comment: Okay, please consider asking this at https://dba.stackexchange.com/